# Executing Multiple queries

Tags: ios

I was following a tutorial.
it was working great..

my doubht is, to execute single query they executed in this method

```
"+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {"
```

as
 `"select coffeeID, coffeeName from coffee""`

that's fine. but for my next view if I want execute a new query like "select * from coffee where abc = 123".

where should I write this query?  I have to create a new method and have to call this new method or what?
how can I execute another query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you're going to use sqlite. I suggest you learn how to add Core Data to your Application.

2) To answer your question. You could add a method to the coffee class to retrieve the data you need. It could be a class method implemented just like:

```
 + (void) getData:(NSString *)dbPath {
    SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // <---Modify the sqlite statement below
        const char *sql = "select coffeeID, coffeeName from coffee"; 
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                coffeeObj.coffeeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)]; // <-- create objects in coffeeObj that you want to do something with.

                coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;

                [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
                [coffeeObj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Make sure you add the corresponding method to the .h file as well.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, just one thing i need to ask..i passed query in it, but how and wheer should i call this "+ (void) getData:(NSString *)dbPath "  method????

Comment: ohk got it running ,i called this method in applicationdidfinish launching.  but one thing, i am getting return data as "<Coffee: 0x7515020>"  in this format. when i close app and run it again, it shows the real data, do u know why this is happening? thanks a ton sir

Comment: Coffee is a class. More precisely it is a data model object. It is a structure that holds your data. You reference NSStrings and such using dot notation. For example in the code above the name of the coffee is stored in coffeeObj.coffeeName.

Comment: so, i am getting returend values as "<Coffee: 0x7515020>", is there any way to get actual value?? thanks again sir

Comment: Coffee *coffeeObj = [coffeeArray objectAtIndex:0]; NSlog(@"%@",coffeeObj.coffeeName); will retrieve the first object in coffeeArray and output it to the console.

Comment: yea got it  running thanks a ton sir..but  my dta is not coming out instantly. i hv to rerun my app to see the data.on first time only data comes up, i can c it no console, but the tablview is not showing up on fist time. than i re run my app and whole data shown up.. wat with this now? i alreday tried [able reload]..but its not working for me.

Comment: Time to ask another question. Your original question has been answered. Accept the answer and ask another question.